# Aim down sight is blurred in the Call of duty Black Ops 3 Beta?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I really wanted to play the new black ops 3 beta and I am having trouble with my sight on my weapon.

When I aim in I see the red dot but its everything around is blurry and the sight is too so I cant get much kills and I don't level up that much.

Is there anything I can do? I am using a Razer Blade 14 inch 8 GB Ram and Intel core 7 processor.

Comment: Is anything you see through the site blurry?  It isn't then this sounds like a realism feature of the game.

Answer (score 2):

Er, we'd need more details than that. Your GPU, for a start. Run "dxdiag" and append a log output from that to your answer. You will have this installed on Windows already, because it comes with DirectX. A screenshot would also really help because depth-of-field is commonly used in this game, and it could be a result of that, but I'd have no way of knowing unless I saw the visual effect myself.

Until then, try turning off depth-of-field in the graphics settings if the game allows it. Also keep in mind that this game hasn't actually been released yet.

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to send you the file? Give me your email so i can send it, ok? Thanks. And ill send a image of my game.

email : nikitaradouski@gmail.com   (please dont use for spam.)

Comment: Just put the contents on pastebin. Host the image on imgur or any other site. Web 2.0 happened a while ago, we don't use email to transfer files any more.